# Automatically avoid more than one node when drawing a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

### Background

Andrew Stacey's answer to [Automatically connect nodes without overlapping other nodes or connections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27899/automatically-connect-nodes-without-overlapping-other-nodes-or-connections) presents code to make a path avoid a node by going through a corner of that node (instead of through the node itself). In it's current state it only lets you specify *one* point to go through. I would like to be able to specify several points to be able to avoid several nodes. ([In chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1926766#1926766) I was advised to make a new question for this issue since it's a different question.)

Note that I will also be happy with answers not building on Andrew's code.

### Problem

Tree diagrams may contain many nodes and it may be hard to draw them so that no path crosses no node. Andrew's code helps to avoid one node but not several.

Here follows a minimal example to illustrate what I mean (note that there may be many more nodes in a tree digrams). Given these nodes

```
\node(a) {\(A\)};
\node(b1) at ($(a)+(1,-0.5)$){\(B_1\)};
\node(b2) at ($(b1)+(0,0.5)$){\(B_2\)};
\node(b3) at ($(b2)+(0,0.5)$){\(B_3\)};
\node(c1) at ($(b1)+(2,0)$){\(C_1\)};
\node(c2) at ($(c1)+(0,0.5)$){\(C_2\)};
\node(c3) at ($(c2)+(0,0.5)$){\(C_3\)};
\node(d) at ($(c2)+(1,0)$){\(D\)};
```

is there a method to draw a path from `(a)` to `(d)` and specify that the path should avoid `(b2)` but also any other node *without* manually specifying angles for the path?

With Andrew's code I can specify only one node to avoid and although it helps to avoid the node I specify, `(b2)`, the path ends up crossing other nodes (the red paths in the image). I would like to be able to *also* specify it to avoid `(b1)`, `(b3)`, `(c1)`, `(c2)` and `(c3)` (so that I get a result such as the green paths in the image).

[image: Example of correct and incorrect paths]

The code to produce the image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  through point/.style={
    to path={%
      \pgfextra{%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztostart)\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@sx}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@sy}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ax}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sx}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ay}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sy}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ex}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sx}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ey}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sy}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@len}{\pt@ex * \pt@ex + \pt@ey * \pt@ey}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@t}{(\pt@ax * \pt@ex + \pt@ay * \pt@ey)/\pt@len}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@t}{(\pt@t > .5 ? 1 - \pt@t : \pt@t)}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@h}{(\pt@ax * \pt@ey - \pt@ay * \pt@ex)/\pt@len}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@y}{\pt@h/(3 * \pt@t * (1 - \pt@t))}%
      }
      (\tikztostart) .. controls +(\pt@t * \pt@ex + \pt@y * \pt@ey, \pt@t * \pt@ey - \pt@y * \pt@ex) and +(-\pt@t * \pt@ex + \pt@y * \pt@ey, -\pt@t * \pt@ey - \pt@y * \pt@ex) .. (\tikztotarget)
    }
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Nodes
\node(a) {\(A\)};
\node(b1) at ($(a)+(1,-0.5)$){\(B_1\)};
\node(b2) at ($(b1)+(0,0.5)$){\(B_2\)};
\node(b3) at ($(b2)+(0,0.5)$){\(B_3\)};
\node(c1) at ($(b1)+(2,0)$){\(C_1\)};
\node(c2) at ($(c1)+(0,0.5)$){\(C_2\)};
\node(c3) at ($(c2)+(0,0.5)$){\(C_3\)};
\node(d) at ($(c2)+(1,0)$){\(D\)};
% Boundaries
\draw[thick] ($(a)+(-0.2,0.9)$) to ($(d)+(0.2,0.9)$);
\draw[thick] ($(a)+(-0.2,-0.9)$) to ($(d)+(0.2,-0.9)$);
% Andrew's code ends up crossing a node
\draw[->,red] (a) to[through point={(b2.north east)}] (d);
\draw[->,red] (a) to[through point={(b2.north west)}] (d);
\draw[->,red] (a) to[through point={(b2.south west)}] (d);
\draw[->,red] (a) to[through point={(b2.south east)}] (d);
\draw[->,red] (a) to[through point={(b2.north)}] (d);
\draw[->,red] (a) to[through point={(b2.south)}] (d);
% Manually specifying angles to show acceptable results
\draw[->,green] (a) to[out=10,in=120] (d);
\draw[->,green] (a) to[out=15,in=163] (d);
\draw[->,green] (a) to[out=-12,in=196] (d);
\draw[->,green] (a) to[out=-10,in=240] (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that Andrews solution still works quite well, but you just need to be more careful in terms of what points to go thru.  For instance `\draw[->,blue] (a) to[through point={(c3.north west)}] (d);` works pretty good.

Comment: @PeterGrill I've improved the example. Note that the example is as minimal as possible. There might be more nodes that in the example so that the line you specified might cross another node because it hasn't been specified to be avoided.

Comment: @Jannis Pohlmann Jannis Pohlmann has written a comprehensive graph drawing library for pgf. This library is part of the CVS version of pgf and runs with LuaTex. Perhaps it can help here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By using [one of Jake's previous answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27318/how-to-write-inside-an-ellipse-in-tikz), I tried to fit the points in an ellipse and the result is not so bad. Also it reduces the manual labor. But there are a few issues which can be improved but I am not able to type `\pgfmathparse` stuff as others do. (I wish I have time!) Anyway, here is the code and some explanation after it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  through point/.style={
    to path={%
      \pgfextra{%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztostart)\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@sx}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@sy}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ax}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sx}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ay}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sy}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ex}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sx}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ey}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sy}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@len}{\pt@ex * \pt@ex + \pt@ey * \pt@ey}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@t}{(\pt@ax * \pt@ex + \pt@ay * \pt@ey)/\pt@len}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@t}{(\pt@t > .5 ? 1 - \pt@t : \pt@t)}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@h}{(\pt@ax * \pt@ey - \pt@ay * \pt@ex)/\pt@len}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@y}{\pt@h/(3 * \pt@t * (1 - \pt@t))}%
      }
      (\tikztostart) .. controls +(\pt@t * \pt@ex + \pt@y * \pt@ey, \pt@t * \pt@ey - \pt@y * \pt@ex) and +(-\pt@t * \pt@ex + \pt@y * \pt@ey, -\pt@t * \pt@ey - \pt@y * \pt@ex) .. (\tikztotarget)
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a) {\(A\)};
\node(b1) at ($(a)+(1,-0.5)$){\(B_1\)};
\node(b2) at ($(b1)+(0,0.5)$){\(B_2\)};
\node(b3) at ($(b2)+(0,0.5)$){\(B_3\)};
\node(c1) at ($(b1)+(2,0)$){\(C_1\)};
\node(c2) at ($(c1)+(0,0.5)$){\(C_2\)};
\node(c3) at ($(c2)+(0,0.5)$){\(C_3\)};
\node(d) at ($(c2)+(1,0)$){\(D\)};
%all the points
\node [draw,ellipse,thick,inner sep=0,fit={(b1) (b2) (b3) (c1) (c2) (c3)}] (avoid1) {};
\draw[->,thick] (a) to[through point={(avoid1.north west) (avoid1.north east)}] (d);
%just the c group
\node [draw,ellipse,blue,inner sep=0,fit={(c1) (c2) (c3)}] (avoid2) {};
\draw[->,blue] (a) to[through point={(avoid2.north)}] (d);
%just the b group
\node [draw,ellipse,yellow,thick,inner sep=1,fit={(b1) (b2) (b3)}] (avoid3) {};
\draw[->,yellow,thick] (a) to[through point={(avoid3.north)}] (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is drawing the bounding ellipses and trying to avoid them. The resulting curves grouped by color. As you can see Andrew's code is still doing a fine job. What is needed is to select the north or the south of the dummy nodes `avoid` which define the curve to pass from below or above. Also I had to define two control nodes to pass through when all obstacles were included see the `avoid1` case. (I am really surprised that it accepted two nodes, superb!). If you think that the resulting curve is overshooting you can decrease the `inner sep` of the ellipse node.

I think TikZ needs this kind of a, say `around`, library. I tried to get the control points of a Beziér curve and other angle computation stuff but I can't understand the math syntax of `pgf` yet. So hope this can help a bit.

---

**EDIT :** I have tried to simplify the whole fitting process then I realized that the fit is not necessary if we can smoothen the path. I checked the manual and only thing that is almost what we want is the `smooth` option with the extra freedom of `tension` parameter.

I have tried it out with the following

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (o) [matrix of nodes, column sep=2cm,nodes=draw,draw=red]{
$A_1$&$B_1$ &$C_1$ &$D_1$\\
$A_2$&$B_2$ &$C_2$ &$D_2$\\
$A_3$&$B_3$ &$C_3$ &$D_3$\\
};
\node (s) at (-6,0) {S};
\node (f) at (6,0) {F};

\draw[blue] plot [smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates{%
(s.east)  (o-2-1.south) (o-2-2.north) (o-1-3.north) (o-1-4.south) (f.west)};
\draw plot [smooth, tension=0.8] coordinates{%
(s.east)  (o-2-1.north) (o-1-2.north) (o-1-4.north) (f.west)};
\draw[yellow,thick] plot [smooth, tension=0.5] coordinates{%
(s.east)  (o-3-1.south) (o-3-4.south) (f.west)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This gives the following result: 
[image]

The `tension` parameter adjusts how smooth the corners should be rendered. Default is reported as `0.55`. So one can still fit some nodes into a bigger shape and use it to avoid but this node-by-node connection seems easier. Also, this introduces new issues such as the out and in angles are slightly awkward and I couldn't make the arrows look normal. I would be glad if someone teaches me how to do it properly.

Comment: Interesting solution. Can you handle cases where you are not allowed to draw the path under `(b1)` or above `(b3)`?

Comment: You mean there is only one direction to go ? I think I don't get the constraint.

Comment: Sorry if I'm vague. My improved example might be clearer. What I mean is that either the path can go between `(b1)` and `(b2)` or between `(b2)` and `(b3)` in avoiding `(b2)` (but not under `(b1)` or above `(b3)` because it avoids `(b2)` too much).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Never thought about it. Let me play around with it for a while.

Comment: @N.N. : Please check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/padded-boundary-of-convex-hull) (again from Jake obviously. He is my TikZ idol recently :p) I think instead of an ellipse you can use this and travel around that shape much easier and more economically

Comment: Aye, @Jake is a wizard. That might work. Can't say I understand the code but someone else might (@SimonByrne made a simplification of mentioned code too).

Answer (score 5):

I asked [a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11180112/82216) recently which depends upon the ability to draw nodes and edges while mostly avoiding overlap. In the course of researching my task, I discovered [dot2tex](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) and [Ladot](http://brighten.bigw.org/projects/ladot/), which may be useful to you. They both use GraphViz, which - as noted in [an answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27996/15911) - has powerful routines for solving this sort of problem. More specifically, these systems can invoke GraphViz's `dot` command, which uses an approach (described [here](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)) that is quite successful at avoiding cases of edges overlapping nodes.

**Example:**

You asked, "is there a method to draw a path from (a) to (d) and specify that the path should avoid (b2) but also any other node without manually specifying angles for the path?" With dot2tex, the answer is yes. Here is how to do it. Save this as `dot2tex_stackexchange_challenge.dot`:

```
digraph g {
graph [ rankdir = "LR" ];
node  [ shape = "plaintext" ];    

a  [ texlbl = "$A$"   ];
b1 [ texlbl = "$B_1$" ];
b2 [ texlbl = "$B_2$" ];
b3 [ texlbl = "$B_3$" ];
c1 [ texlbl = "$C_1$" ];
c2 [ texlbl = "$C_2$" ];
c3 [ texlbl = "$C_3$" ];
d  [ texlbl = "$D$"   ];

{rank=same; b1 b2 b3;} // Not necessary here, but could be handy later
{rank=same; c1 c2 c3;} // Ditto

a  ->  d;
a  ->  b1 [style="invis"];
a  ->  b2 [style="invis" weight="10"];
a  ->  b3 [style="invis"];
b1 ->  c1 [style="invis"];
b2 ->  c2 [style="invis" weight="10"];
b3 ->  c3 [style="invis"];
c1 ->  d  [style="invis"];
c2 ->  d  [style="invis" weight="10"];
c3 ->  d  [style="invis"];
}
```

Then execute these commands:

```
$ dot2tex --crop --margin 1em --autosize dot2tex_stackexchange_challenge.dot > dot2tex_stackexchange_challenge.tex
$ pdflatex dot2tex_stackexchange_challenge.tex
```

In order to generate this:

[image]

Note that most of the code in my example is concerned with typesetting the nodes and laying them out in same 1,3,3,1 pattern you gave in your question. The bit that does the work of creating an edge from `a` to `d` that avoids the other nodes is just the line `a  ->  d;`, plus of course the magic of the `dot` command's algorithm.

Comment: Interesting. This is more of a comment than an answer in its current state. Do you have any example or hunch how to go about to solve the problem?

Comment: I've now fleshed it out into a full answer.

Comment: Do you mean including in your answer a description of how the nodes are avoided?

Comment: Well, it kind of happens "automagically". By default, dot2tex invokes GraphViz's `dot` command, which uses an approach (described [here](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)) that is quite successful at avoiding cases of edges overlapping nodes.

Comment: You might want to include that in your answer.

Comment: I'd thought the link to the answer to your previous question would have been enough, but I've now expanded the answer along the lines you suggested. No harm in extra clarity :)